# serializing session state in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, session-state, nopcommerce

I'm trying to store session state in SQL instead of InProc in our nopcommerce 1.9 install. When I make the requisite changes to the web.config I get this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and
>   'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects,
>   and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are
>   not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization
>   is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Unable to serialize the
>   session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will
>   serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable
>   objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same
>   restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom
>   session state store in 'Custom' mode.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SerializationException: Type
>   'NopSolutions.NopCommerce.BusinessLogic.Categories.Category' in
>   Assembly 'Nop.BusinessLogic, Version=1.9.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.]
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType
>   type) +9449041
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type
>   type, StreamingContext context) +247
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
>   +160    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Type
>   objectType, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext
>   context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter
>   converter, SerializationBinder binder) +371
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteArray(WriteObjectInfo
>   objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, WriteObjectInfo memberObjectInfo)
>   +205    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo
>   objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo) +651
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object
>   graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
>   +444    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
>   +133    System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +1762
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to serialize the session state. In
>   'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session
>   state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or
>   MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies
>   if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in
>   'Custom' mode.]
>   System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value,
>   BinaryWriter writer) +1847
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.WriteValueToStreamWithAssert(Object
>   value, BinaryWriter writer) +34
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Serialize(BinaryWriter
>   writer) +638
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.Serialize(SessionStateStoreData
>   item, Stream stream) +244
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.SerializeStoreData(SessionStateStoreData
>   item, Int32 initialStreamSize, Byte[]& buf, Int32& length, Boolean
>   compressionEnabled) +67
>   System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext
>   context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean
>   newItem) +140
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object
>   source, EventArgs eventArgs) +807
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +148    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

Somebody PLEASE tell me I don't need to serialize every object in Nopcommerce to do this!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the exception says your Type

`NopSolutions.NopCommerce.BusinessLogic.Categories.Category`

is not serializable. I dont know the implementation of that type but you can try to decorate the type with the `[Serializable]` attribute.

**If you cant do this you can simply write the id of the object to your session.**

If you want your session stored in sql server, every object your write into your session needs to be serializable.

#### More Information

- [Steps for Session InProc Mode to Session StateServer](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.de/2009/06/steps-for-session-inproc-mode-to.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how can I write the id of the object to my session, for example if I have class I want to serialize how I can write that class id to my session? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Adding the `[Serializable]` attribute (`<Serializable()>` in VB) automatically makes your class serializable. All the members in your class need to be serializable too. So suppose there are object references in your class. Then the classes which those objects belong to need to have the `[Serializable]` attribute too. Basic types are automatically serializable.